# accessing a bit in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

if i have a variable of type byte named `eFlagContents` holding a value of `0000 0010` how would I go about accessing each bit individually so i can output them? I've tried the following that only works when i have characters stored in the variable.

```
MOV ECX, 8
outputLoop:
        MOVZX EAX, counter
        MOV AL, BYTE PTR [eFlagContents + EAX ]
        MOV EBX, 1
        CALL WriteBinB
        CALL Crlf
        INC counter
        LOOP outputLoop
```

with the only difference being that for characters it would be `WriteChar`

Answer (score 0):

```
TEST AL, BYTE 0x04 (or whatever the hex value of the bit is)
```

whether the bit is set or not will bin the C flag; use `JZ` to make decision.

If the bit we want to access sis in AL to begin with, we can do this (clobbers DX)

```
MOV DL, 0
SHL DL, CL
MOV AL, BYTE PTR [eFlagContents]
TEST AL, DL
```

Comment: `test` always clears CF because AND can't carry-out.  The result of whether that bit is zero or not will be in ZF.  Also, you'd more likely want to just `shr eax, 1` in a loop so you can isolate the low one easily, and add it to `'0'`.

Comment: If you want to test a variable bit-position, use `bt eax, edx`.  *That* produces a result in CF.